# Upgrading SQL Server 2008 to 2014

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to 2014.
But I got these two failed reports below:

[image]

[image]

And the situation of the installs I CURRENTLY have is this:

[image]

And then I have two instances inside it that I can connect to:
One of them looks like this:

[image]

and the other one looks like this:

[image]

**So what should I do now?  I want the shell to be `2014 Developer Edition` instead of `2008 R2 Developer Edition`.**

Comment: Start with the first error message and follow what is says...

Comment: The build number for SP2 is [10.50.4000.0](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com). You have SP1 installed (from the same site).

Comment: You have to upgrade to SP2 before upgrading to 2014 as the dialog says.

Comment: How can I just upgrade the SHELL and NOT the instances inside it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you serious? The first message literally tells you exactly what is wrong.

You must first install Service Pack 2....

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30437

Comment: I got this error when I wanted to go to SP 4, Ok so now downloading SP 2 then:  "The version of SQL Server instance Shared Component does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 10.51.2500.0, and the expected SQL Server version is 10.0.1600.22."

Comment: No need to be condescending.

Comment: @SQLMason - I actually think this should be closed and is not a valid question. This site should be for programming questions, not help reading plainly clear error messages

Comment: How can I just upgrade the SHELL and NOT the instances inside it ?

Comment: SSMS is now a separate application, so you do not, you simply install the new version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms